# Floated Images and Text Wrap in Fluid Design

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, word-wrap

I've search for a solution to the issue I'm addressing but couldn't find an answer.

I have a fluid div, within with is text and two stacked images that display inline. I want the text to wrap the images as the viewport narrows. At mobile viewport widths, the images need to appear at 100% width beneath the text, which also is at 100% width.

The only way I've been able to stack the images at desktop widths is to place them into a floated div with a set width, with the image div placed before the text in the html.

If I place the image div after the text, the text spans the width of the container at desktop widths, pushing the images beneath the text.

However, this is the only way to get the images to slide beneath the text at mobile viewport widths.

Thanks in advance for any ideas -- this seems straightforward but I cannot get it to work as needed.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FRwLp/2/).

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="content">

    <div class="primaryContent">

        <div class="aboutImage">

            <img class="img" src="http://s14.postimg.org/t11gqnz5p/square.png">
            <img class="img" src="http://s14.postimg.org/t11gqnz5p/square.png">

        </div>

        <h1>About</h1>

        <p>A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text.  A whole bunch of text.  A whole bunch of text.  A whole bunch of text.  A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text.  A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text.</p>

        <p> A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text. A whole bunch of text.</p>

    </div><!--end primaryContent -->

    <aside class="sideBar group">

        <p>A bunch on content. A bunch on content. A bunch on content. A bunch on content. A bunch on content. A bunch on content. A bunch on content. A bunch on content. A bunch on content.</p>

    </aside>

</content>
```

And the CSS:

```
.content {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

.primaryContent {
        display:inline-block;
        width: 70%;
        float:left;
        vertical-align:top;
        background-color:lightgrey;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

.aboutImage {
        width: 40%;
        float:right;
    }

.img {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.img img {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.sideBar {
    width:29%;
    float:right;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border-left: solid 1px black;
}

.group:after {
        content:" ";
        display:table;
        clear:both;
    }
```

Comment: there are many ways to do this.. if you can answer a few questions. can the images be css backgrounds?  this way you have two divs that are displayed only in the view width you want when you want

Comment: The site will be managed via a CMS and needs to be editable by the business user. I'm pretty sure I could hack this in, but it would be way better / safer to use an approach other than css background images.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the layout of your DOM.

As you currently have it you would need add a lot of additional code to get the mobile responsive experience you are looking for.

I would suggest nesting your images and content into a container and floating the entire container left

```
<div class="content">

  <div class="leftContent">

    <div class="mainContent">

           <!--Text Comes Here-->
    </div>

    <div class="images">

           <!--Images to be here-->
    </div>

  </div>
  <aside class="sideBar group">
           <!--Sidebar content here-->
  </aside>
```

this will allow you to float elements as you wish and make the neccecary changes with [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

I have made a fiddle for you here : http://jsfiddle.net/8QmLL/

Also check your ending HTML Tag. You are closing a `</content>` but you should be closing a `</div>`

Comment: This is a mobile-first site and all media queries / styles are in place. The source presented here is highly modified for the purpose of presenting the scenario via a fiddle (should have been more explicit about this, but behavior is explained in my post). Your solution nests two columns within the main column, which doesn't allow text to wrap. This need I *was* explicit about -- "I want text to wrap the images as the viewport narrows."